# Momentum and Lorentz invariant

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, momentum, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

We know conservation of momentum is invariant under Lorentz transformation. Is momentum i.e the physical quantity itself invariant under Lorentz transformation?

Answer (score 2):

It's important to be clear what you mean by "momentum". If you mean the classical 3D vector, then this is clearly not invariant since observers moving relative to one another will observe different 3-momenta. However, in relativity there is a 4-momentum, which is a 4D vector which has energy as the time component and classical momentum as the 3 spatial components. This *is* Lorentz covariant (not "invariant", as its components change: but they do so like any other spacetime vector, and the magnitude is invariant). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum for more details.